# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#transaction_form"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am learning to write feature specs using rspec and capybara. I am trying to write spec for an application, which handles transactions. My transaction controller is as follows:

```
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
  end

  def create
    transaction = Transaction.new(transaction_params)
    transaction.account = current_account
    if transaction.save && transaction.account.save
      flash[:success] = 'Transaction successfull'
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Insufficient balance'
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

It's view is as follows transactions/new:

```
<div class = 'row'>
<div class = 'col-xs-12'>
    <%= form_for(@transaction, id: 'transaction_form', :html => {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form'}) do |t| %>
        <div class = 'form-group'>
          <div class = 'control-label col-sm-2'>
            <%= t.label :amount %>
          </div>

      <div class = 'col-sm-8'>
        <%= t.text_field :amount, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter amount', autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = 'form-group'>
      <div class = 'control-label col-sm-2'>
        <%= t.label :transaction_type %>
      </div>

      <div class = 'col-sm-8'>
        <%= t.select :transaction_type, Transaction.transaction_types.keys %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = 'form-group'>
      <div class = 'col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'>
        <%= t.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I added `id: transaction_form` to form to avoid ambiguous error. 
The spec code is as follows:

```
RSpec.feature 'Transactions', type: :feature do
context 'create new transaction' do
scenario 'should be successfull' do
  visit new_transaction_path
  within('#transaction_form') do
    fill_in 'Amount', with: '60'
  end
  click_button 'Submit'
  expect(page).to have_content('Transaction successfull')
end
end
end
```

On running this spec, however,I get error as:

```
 1) Transactions create new transaction should be successfull
    Failure/Error:
       within('#transaction_form') do
         fill_in 'Amount', with: '60'
       end

 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#transaction_form"
```

What is it I am missing? If I use `form` directly, it is throwing the ambiguous error as it is getting the same element from different file. What is wrong with this code?

Also, the /transactions/new page will be displayed only if the user is logged in. So will this also affect the transaction spec? If yes, then what should be done?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page you want to interact with is only visible when the user is logged in, then you need to log the user in.  That also means you will need to create the user you're going to log in before the test starts. Usually that would be done using either Rails fixtures, or a factory (like the [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot) gem). Once you have create the user then you'll need to log them in, which can be as simple as visiting the login page and entering the users username and password. If you're using a gem for authentication it may provide a test mode which allows for bypassing actually visiting the login page in order to speed up tests (ie. devise provides this - https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara)

Comment: Ok i'll try this.

Comment: I used warden to create user to perform the transactions. The user is getting logged in properly. But still I am getting the same error of 'Unable to find css'. Is there anything wrong in giving id to the form of new_transaction?